# How to send a @silent message with Nextcord?

Tags: discord, nextcord

To send a [silent message](https://discord.com/blog/discord-update-february-20-2023-changelog) as a user, you simply have to begin your message with `@silent`. For example, sending `@silent This message is silent` results in :

[image: example of a @silent message sent by a user in Discord]

I thought the same principle would apply to bots, but it looks like i was wrong :

```py
await interaction.channel.send("@silent This message is not silent")
```

results in :

[image: failing example of a @silent message sent by a bot in Discord]

**How can bots send silent messages with Nextcord ? Are they even capable of it ?**

I did not find anything in the [Nextcord documentation](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with nextcord itself, but in discord.py you have to pass it as a parameter. [Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interactionresponse).

```py
await interaction.channel.send("This message should be silent", silent=True)
```